# Реализация метода увеличения одинаковых чисел в строке

Tags: c++, строки

Необходимо реализовать функцию void IncrementEquals(string &src), которая увеличивает все одинаковые числа, встречающиеся в строке на 1.

Тело программы написано, алгоритм не могу реализовать.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <climits>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void IncrementEquals(string &src);

int main(){

   string input;
   IncrementEquals(input);

    return 0;
}

void IncrementEquals(string &src){

    getline(cin, src);
    istringstream instr(src);
    int sum = 0;
    unsigned int count = 0;
    int currentValue;

    // Пропускаем все символы пока не встретим первую цифру
    while (instr && !isdigit(instr.peek())){
        instr.get();
    }
    // Если мы не дошли до конца строки и встретили первую цифру, то читаем все число
    while (instr >> currentValue){
    // ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ РЕШЕНИЕ


        while (instr && !isdigit(instr.peek())){
            instr.get();
        }
    }


    istringstream inResult(src);
    string result;
    // Заносим все символы из входной строки до первого числа
    while (inResult && !isdigit(inResult.peek())){
        result += inResult.get();
    }
    // Если встретили число, читаем его (что бы пропустить)
    while (inResult >> currentValue){
        // ТУТ ДОЛЖЕН БЫТЬ ВЫВОД
        result += to_string();
        while (inResult && !isdigit(inResult.peek())){
            result += inResult.get();
        }
    }

    // Вывод результатов
    cout << result << endl; 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Так-как автор, не смог описать вопрос правильно, еще и агрится, даю только подсказку, как сделать:

```
vector<int> numbers;
string str = "345ваыпвыап 345 сваца 34 са2 4";
bool IsDigit = false;
int number = 0;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    const char chr = str[i];
    if (chr >= '0' && chr <= '9') {
        const int digit = chr - '0';
        number = number * 10 + digit;
        IsDigit = true;
    } else {
        if (IsDigit) {
            numbers.push_back(++number);
            number = 0;
            IsDigit = false;
        }
    }
}
if (IsDigit) {
    numbers.push_back(++number);
}
```

Данный код, выводит массив чисел (+1 к каждому числу):

> 346
>     346
>     35
>     3
>     5

А дальше уважаемая наша хамщица, напрягайте мозги и раскладывайте, что нужно и как нужно в строке, если вам вообще это нужно было..

Comment: 15 6 C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\share\AnotherTry\Untitled1.cpp [Error] no matching function for call to 'for_each(std::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::basic_string<char>::iterator, main()::<lambda(char)>)'

Comment: А ты попробуй вместо 1 2 и 3 вбить 11 12 и 13

Comment: Попробуйте со строкой `"первая цифра (9)"`. В её задании указано "число", а не "цифра". Мне кажется, что программа должна корректно улаживать такие случаи - `"первая цифра (10)"`

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего задача была такой:

> Написать функцию `void IncrementEquals(string &src)`, которая увеличивает все одинаковые числа, встречающиеся в строке на 1. В основной функции продемонстрировать ее работу применительно к строке вводимой пользователем.
>
> Пример:«33 bottles of 33 bugs on 13» → «34 bottles of 34 bugs on 13»

К примеру, можно сделать через вектор массивов:

```cpp
void IncrementEquals(string &src)
{
    int begin = 0;
    int end = 0;
    vector<array<int, 3>> arr;

    for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(static_cast<int>(src[i]))) 
        {
            begin = i;
            i++;

            for (; isdigit(static_cast<int>(src[i])); i++);     

            end = i;
            arr.push_back(array<int, 3> ({stoi(src.substr(begin, end-begin)), begin, end}));
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.size(); j++)
        {
            if (arr[i][0] == arr[j][0])
            { 
                src.replace(arr[i][1], arr[i][2]-arr[i][1], to_string(arr[i][0] + 1));
                src.replace(arr[j][1], arr[j][2]-arr[j][1], to_string(arr[j][0] + 1));
            }
        }
    }
    cout << src;
}
```

P.S. привет мученикам из МИЭМа, если не ошибаюсь:))